# How can I import data from an ambiguous URL?

Tags: vba, excel

This is almost working!!  But not quite!

```
        If link.innerHTML Like "*Upload Questionnaire*" Then
            link.Click

            Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            objIE.Navigate strURL

            Do While objIE.ReadyState <> 4 And objIE.Busy
               DoEvents
            Loop


                    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
                    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", strSQL, False
                    XMLHTTP.send
                    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
                    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.responseText
                    Set tbl = html.getElementsByTagName("Table")
                    Set tr_coll = tbl(0).getElementsByTagName("TR")
                    For Each tr In tr_coll
                        j = 1
                        Set td_col = tr.getElementsByTagName("TD")
                        For Each td In td_col
                            Cells(row + 1, j).Value = td.innerText
                            j = j + 1
                        Next
                        row = row + 1
                    Next
        End If
```

For one thing, the code doesn't pause and wait for the browser to finish loading.

```
Do While objIE.ReadyState <> 4 And objIE.Busy
   DoEvents
Loop
```

Also, I'm feeding in a Parent URL, like this:

```
strSQL = "https://blah_blah_blah_CampaignID=" & cell.Value
```

The line below doesn't work.

```
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", strSQL, False
```

Somehow I need to pass in the Child URL that opens from the Parent URL.  This is the parent URL: `strSQL = "https://blah_blah_blah_CampaignID=" & cell.Value`

When:  `link.Click`
runs then the Child URL opens, but I don't know how to  reference the Child URL.  How can I do that?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the link is contained within the class, rather than looping through all `a` elements within the document itself, use `getElementsByClassName()` to grab ever element in your target class, and then loop through those.

Something like:

```
For each classElement in IE.document.getElementsByClassName("thClass")
  For each linkElement in classElement.getElementsByTagName("a")
    'check for innerHTML, etc.
  Next
Next
```

If the class is within the link, you can just flip the loops.

This should work, for example:

```
Public Sub LookADemo()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer, doc As HTMLDocument
Dim thisClass As IHTMLElement2, thisLink As IHTMLElement
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.navigate "https://www.google.com"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until (ie.ReadyState >= READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE) And (ie.Busy = False)
Set doc = ie.Document
For Each thisClass In doc.getElementsByClassName("hp")
  For Each thisLink In thisClass.getElementsByTagName("a")
    Debug.Print thisLink.InnerText
  Next
Next
ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that.  I get an error here: For Each classElement In IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("thClass") The error message is 'Object doesn't support this property or method'.

Comment: You may need to declare classElement as IHTMLElement2

Comment: I think I'm missing something pretty basic here, but not sure exactly what.  I'm going to revise my original post with my updated code.  Please see the script above.  Thanks for trying to help me!!